# Block not showing on a matching path (menu item duplicate)

Tags: routes, path-aliases, blocks

I have a strange situation and would like to verify it with you.

I have a menu block of main manu level 2+ links.

```
Corporate     [<--block title, level 1 of Main Menu]
  About Us    [corporate/about-us]
  Services    [corporate/services]
  Contact Us  [corporate/contact-us]
```

It is configured to appear only for pages with addresses matching the pattern `corporate/*`. So far so good. But in order to better communicate the Contact Us page, I created manually a duplicate of the Contact Us (with the same `[corporate/contact-us]` alias) at level 1 of the Main Menu. Once that duplicate is there, the block disappears from the Contact Us page.

Is there a Drupal culprit I bumped into? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps on the Contact Us page, the block is trying to display child menu entries for the new level 1 "Contact Us" item, and there are none? The block won't get rendered if there's no content.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. If so, what do you think would be the best strategy to have this kind of duplicated menu item pointing to Contact Us?

Comment: I think it makes sense to first verify my assumption by creating some child menu entries under the level 1 Contact Us item and checking if the block starts to display on the page. Is that what's happening?

Comment: The key is [menu_tree_set_path] (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_tree_set_path/7)